# JS object using `this` gives an undefined result

Tags: javascript, oop

Ok here is a very simple JS object. Three attributes are strings, the fourth is a function.

```
var myStringBuilder = {
  protocol: "http://",
  host: "www.mysite.com",
  fullPath: this.protocol + this.host + "/just/for/fun/",
  getFullString: function() {
    return this.fullPath;
  }
}

console.log(myStringBuilder.getFullString());  // Returns "NaN/just/for/fun"
```

In `fullPath`, `this.protocol` and `this.host` are both undefined. Why does this happen?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7zLN/)

Comment: It sees a plus sign so it converts it to a number. Try this: this.partOne + ""+this.partTwo + "/just/for/fun/",

Comment: Alex - please attempt in the jsfiddle before answering, as your comment is incorrect. JS also uses + for string concatenation and won't coerce two strings into numerics just because of this operator.

Comment: Yes in js it is a concatenation and addition. It is unpredictable. Just turn fullpath into a function and return the concatenation

Comment: it really isn't unpredictable...

Comment: the pb is that you are not in a function context, so `this` does not refer to the object but to "something" outside (Window or caller function)

Comment: the caller function is myStringBuilder.

Comment: @DonnyP Please tell me if i'm wrong but as far i can see in your code, myStringBuilder is _not_ a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally JavaScript objects are constructed based on a hashing algorithm. So, they keys may not logically appear in the order we define them. In this case, `fullPath` gets defined first and when the value is assigned, it depends on `partOne` and `partTwo` where they havn't got defined yet. That is why they are `undefined` while defining `fullPath`.

If you must construct an Object like this, I would recommend a constructor function, like this

```
function MyStringBuilder() {
    this.protocol = "http://";
    this.host = "www.mysite.com";
    this.fullPath = this.protocol + this.host + "/just/for/fun/";
}

MyStringBuilder.prototype.getFullString = function() {
    return this.fullPath;
}

myStringBuilder();
```

The advantage of this method is that, you can customize the object creation dynamically. For example, you can pass `protocol` or `host` values like this

```
function MyStringBuilder(protocol, host) {
    this.protocol = protocol || "http://";
    this.host     = host     || "www.mysite.com";
    this.fullPath = this.protocol + this.host + "/just/for/fun/";
}
```

with this change, you should be able to decide the `protocol` and `host` at runtime.

Comment: Ahhh thanks thefourtheye. In that case, is it not possible to set properties based off other properties?  Basically I am building up a URL, and its useful to be able to take chunks up to certain points

Comment: @DonnyP You can. But you may have to use a constructor function, like I included in my answer.

Comment: To use the constructor way, I may suggest the function named as MyStringBuild(protocol, host)

Comment: @Bargitta Oops, sorry I forgot the convention. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2):

To get around part of the hash being undefined, you can use functions instead of calculated values. This will delay evaluation.

```
var myStringBuilder = {
  partOne: "http://",
  partTwo: "www.mysite.com",
  fullPath: function(){ return this.partOne + this.partTwo + "/just/for/fun/" }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i agree with all the valuable information in previous answers, to answer to the precise point in the question, the `fullPath` property is not properly defined because it is not initialized in a function context, so `this` does not refer to the object myStringBuilder.